# HTML color syntax within a single quote [Sublime]

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, sublimetext2, color-scheme

Heey guys,

I've a question,
i've been looking for a theme for sublime(or a way to edit a theme) that will colorsheme html within a single quote (while writing in Javascript)
[Example]
[image]
Can you guys give me a hand? 
I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: is this JS that you're working with?

Comment: @MattDMo Yeah it is, sorry for not explaining this!

Comment: I have never tried, but I bet you could find where the scope of the single quotes are defined in the `JavaScript.tmLanguage` ( I think its `<string>string.quoted.single.js</string>`, modify them so that the you have a `<beginCaptures>` and `<endCaptures>` and shove the contents of the whole `HTML.tmLanguage` file between them.

Comment: the good news is there is a way to do this, the bad news is that I'm really busy right now and won't be able to answer for a little while. It involves hacking the `JavaScript.tmLanguage` language definition file, and isn't too difficult, but I need to test it out first. Hang tight!

Comment: @AGS Sounds logic, only now i killed my whole Javascript.tmLanguage file XD haha, i'm going to keep trying, let you know if i succeeded! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @MattDMo I'm trying to get this to work but i always get a Duplicate key warning back. You would be the greatest if you know how to do it!

Comment: @AGS - that's kind of the idea, except you can just reference other syntaxes instead of having to copy-and-paste the whole thing. I'll try to post an answer tonight if possible...

Comment: @MattDMo Did you have any time to help me out with this ? :)

Comment: I'm still having some issues, and I just haven't had a chance to spend serious time on it, as work and family life have intervened the last few days. Still working on it, though!

Comment: @MattDMo Off course! family and work are so much more important then this tiny problem. I can do my work without but it would make my life (and i think of a few others) so much easier! Great to hear that you are working on it! good stuff!

Comment: @MattDMo Heey men, i hope i'm not annoying you but did you succeed with the files or not?